# Video onlick event in mobile view in react is not working. Can anyone help me to solve this problem so that I can make use of onClick event in mobile

Tags: reactjs, video, mobile, react-hooks

Video onlick event in mobile view in react is not working. Events like onPointerEnter, onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd are working on mobile view but I have to use onClick event only to open popup in both desktop and mobile view.

Codesandbox code is available on https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-rain-z8lb9o?file=/src/App.js

Steps:

1. Open inspect and check console log 'test' in desktop view.
2. Not able to console log 'test' in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another event handler for touch. When we use a touch screen device then it's not clicking, it's touch.

```
onTouchStart={() => {
  console.log("test2");
}}
```